# Cryptic error under iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-ui, mobile-safari

When I load the landing page of my application under iPad I am getting the following error in my javascript (I have several different javascript files loaded):

```
JavaScript: Error
undefined
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

It neither tells me which file it comes from, nor what exactly the error is. Any ideas of how I can debug this in an easier, more understandable way? The application works fine on all major desktop browsers including IE7.

Comment: It's pretty generic (it means you're trying to call a function that...does not exist). You should at least find which function fails (and there could be TONS of reasons for that).

Comment: Yeah I understood that much, but still is there are way for me to get a more specific error message under this browser?

Comment: What browsers have you tried? Other browsers (not just major) may give  a better error description. Many browsers suppress JS errors so they may be there even if there's no error message

Comment: This error is only thrown under mobile safari, all other browsers give no errors and the page is rendered just fine.

Comment: Enable the debug console on Safari, there you should have a more detailed description of the error (and...the line number).

Comment: Instructions here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Comment: My console is actually enabled for me to see the above described message. I was wondering if there is a plugin or anything of the sort which would actually take me to the specific line in the javascript which throws that error.

Comment: Console _should_ tell you the line number too...

Comment: However it doesn't. What I have posted above is the entire information the console gives me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue! I had my app hosted on IIS express and all my javascript references were done via a virtual directory on localhost.

So I had the following references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/folder/script.js"></script>
```

When I changed it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1.1.1.1/folder/script.js"></script>
```

It all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate answer that might help people who encounter the same error message:

**1. iWebInspector**

[iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/) is a debugging tool for the iOS simulator. With it, you can load a site in the simulator's browser and get access to webkit's web inspector, to help debugging

**2. Remote debugging**

A very easy way to achieve this is to use iOS6's remote debugging interface, with Safari. However, at this moment it's not publicly available (won't be longer though), and requires an iPad with iOS6 and Safari 6. You can read more about this [here](http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/24936855546/what-ios-6-mobile-safari-offers-front-end-devs), but most of the details are still under NDA.

Remote debugging it's something that I used recently and seems very nice, but iWebInspector and the simulator were good too and I still use them for web stuff